# How to center Picture Slideshow Library Web Part

Tags: web-part, css, picture-library

I have a scenario that I'm pretty new with so I need you guys' understanding.

- I have a Picture Library called Cool Animals which obviously contains photos of animals.
- I then created a web part page using Header, Footer, 3 Columns template, added a Picture Library Slideshow Web Part that pulled photos from Cool Animals Pic Library and added a Content Editor Web Part for to put a title at the top called Cool Animals shown below:

[image]

The problem is that even when I added the web part to the middle of the zone, it is still displaying the pictures to the far left. I want it to display the picture slideshow in the middle directly below the Cool Animals title. I have checked and it seems that CSS is the answer but would need assistance in executing the task. I'm a Site Owner in this case and need help in how to access the web part's CSS, make changes, and save those changes back to the site. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create the css so the site looks the way you want it to. You do not want to alter SharePoint´s own CSS, but create your own CSS that overrides SharePoint CSS. Either create a new file that contains your CSS and upload to SharePoint (eg. in style library) and then link it in to your page. Or use a script editor webpart and write the css directly on to the page.

If you need some more explanation on the prosess just notify me!

Comment: Thanks Andreas! Based on the options you gave me I want to go with route of using a Content Editor Web Part (same as script editor right?). Since I'll be going that route how do I access the css of the web part from the CEWP? Please advise.

Comment: Add <style type="text/css">
   #WebPartID .class   {
      //css here
   }
</style>

Comment: Hi eVT. Would I use a Content Editor Web Part to place the script tag you mentioned? Also, and sorry for the newb question, how can I get the WebPartID of the Picture Slideshow?

Comment: Content editor web part will work fine. To get the web part ID - use developer tools of your browser (hit f12) and use the inspector tool to select the web part. Read The html code, it should be something like ID=webpartid... :)

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I've been checking out some CSS scripts to put to CEWP but running into road blocks (not working). I found the class of the web part and would like to know if you have any articles you have ran into that could accomplish what I'm trying to do. Anything would help.

Comment: You can try something like this CSS `#webpartid{width: auto; margin: 0 auto;}` for the `width` you can spesify some value, but I´m not sure how wide your webpart is. If this does not work - copy your html code here and I´ll write you the CSS.

Comment: @Andreas I have attempted and even when I used your suggestion with CEWP I am running into road blocks. When you mentioned copy HTML here were you refering to the script tag when I inspect the web part element? I would assume you are not referring to the page source. Please advise and again thanks for working with me.